# Error for socket

Tags: c++, udp

```
if ( sendto(sf, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, addr_size) < 0 )
```

Can you tell me what is the error number 29 in the UDP socket program . When I am using the `sendto()` function, it gives me number for error as 29.

Comment: Use e.g. [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) to print a message with the error, or [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to send datagrams longer than 64KiB ? You can't do that with UDP (due to the length of the size header field).

Comment: http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/errcmp.html

Comment: but first time when sending then it shows the receive success and after when seond time i am sending its give me Illegal Seek error.

Comment: By the way, the error is `ESPIPE`, and you should not get it from [`sendto`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sendto.html) which leads me to think you're doing something really weird in your code. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?